# Inserting optparse input into a function call

Tags: python, python-2.7, optparse

I know there has tobe a better way to do this.  So I call it with
"myApp -v 182".  I want that 182 to be turned into hex and then be fed into another function I import (doThis).  The only way I've found is sort of lame using the exec function.  I'm sure there must be a better. Python 2.7

```
from optparsese import OptionParser
import doThis
usage = "usage: %prog [options] arg1 arg2"
parser = OptionParser(usage)

parser.add_option("-v", "--value", action="store", type="int", dest="value",
                  help="enter the decimal value of the hex you wish")

(options,args) = parser.parse_args()
def myFunc():
    myHex = hex(options.value)
    # the first two values are fixed, the last is what needs to supply
    doThis.withThis(0xbc,0xa3,myHex)
    # the only way I've gotten this to work is kind of lame
    exec('doThis.withThis(0xbc,0xa3,' + myHex + ')')

myFunc()
```

I get the typical "No method matches the given arguments" when I try to insert the myHex directly.  It works with the exec function but I'm guessing that is not the proper way.
Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to call `hex()` on the value:

```
doThis.withThis(0xbc, 0xa3, options.value)
```

`hex()` returns a *string*, while using hex notation in Python code produces a regular integer instead:

```
>>> 0xa3
163
>>> hex(163)
'0xa3'
>>> type(0xa3)
<type 'int'>
>>> type(hex(163))
<type 'str'>
>>> eval(hex(163))
163
```

Note how `0xa3` is really just a different way of spelling `163` in decimal, and `eval()` turned the value into an integer again.

`optparse` cannot do the same for your 'integer' value entered on the command line; by setting `type="int"` you instruct it to recognise the same syntax. From the [*Standard option types* documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/optparse.html#optparse-standard-option-types):

> if the number starts with `0x`, it is parsed as a hexadecimal number

and the output is the same; `0xa3` on the command line gives you the integer value `163`:

```
>>> import optparse
>>> optparse._parse_int('0xa3')
163
```